# asciidoctor: FAILED: 'asciidoctor-plantuml' could not be loaded

Tags: docker, asciidoc, asciidoctor, plantuml

In my docker container, running `asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-plantuml my_doc.adoc` gets me `asciidoctor: FAILED: 'asciidoctor-plantuml' could not be loaded`.
To reproduce the issue:

````
$ docker run -it -v $WHERE_ADOCS:/documents/ asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor
77687352778d:/documents# asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-plantuml --trace my_doc.adoc
    from <internal:/usr/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/lib/asciidoctor/cli/options.rb:281:in `block in parse!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/lib/asciidoctor/cli/options.rb:279:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/lib/asciidoctor/cli/options.rb:279:in `parse!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/lib/asciidoctor/cli/options.rb:34:in `parse!'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/lib/asciidoctor/cli/invoker.rb:24:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/bin/asciidoctor:13:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/asciidoctor-2.0.18/bin/asciidoctor:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/asciidoctor:25:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/asciidoctor:25:in `<main>'```
````

with the result like above. I've been following this [README of plantuml extention for asciidoctor](https://github.com/hsanson/asciidoctor-plantuml).
Do I need to start the *plantuml-server* for generating the .html?

```
11:34 $ docker images
REPOSITORY                       TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
plantuml/plantuml-server         jetty     92b40d953f4e   3 weeks ago    410MB
asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor   latest    dc8b75bfd089   4 weeks ago    685MB
```

so both images exists in my local. Is there anything I miss?
Any hint is appreciated....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `asciidoctor-plantuml`, `asciidoctor-diagram` works flawless:

```
77687352778d:/documents# asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-diagram my_doc.adoc
```

with the expected `my_doc.html` with the *embedded* `plantuml` being generated.

Answer (score 0):

Debian doesn't have `asciidoctor-diagram` but `asciidoctor-kroki`:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-asciidoctor-kroki
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-kroki my.adoc
```